# How to drag order of programs on the start bar in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

In Windows 7, seeing that you can drag and rearrange different applications, is there any way to rearrange separate instances of the *same* application?

I have an image to show you what I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[7 Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker)** - This programs enables you to tweak your Windows 7 taskbar.

[image]

Features:

- Show standard window menu on right click instead of jump list.
- Close or focus a window on middle click instead of running a new instance.
- **Disable grouping** of windows by file path or application id.
- Cycle through windows of a grouped button on left click instead of showing a thumbnails preview.
- Open with while dropping a file on a taskbar button instead of pinning.
- Disable thumbnail previews.

Answer (score 2):

By default, programs with the same application ID are grouped together. You can change this with a simple registry tweak.

Open regedit (Start -> type "regedit" in the search box and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> ). Expand the treeview to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer`, modify the **TaskbarGlomming** value and set it to **0** to prevent the grouping.